# MySQL: How to exclude duplicates with a join?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all of the users who belong to a group. My `group_members` table keeps track of which groups a user belongs to.

```
group_members ( group_id , user_id )
```

So in my `group_members` table, a `user_id` may appear multiple times because a user can belong to many groups. I'm using an `innerJoin()` to pull the user information for each `user_id`. However, I only want to display a user's name once when I retrieve it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/select.html). Either:

```
select distinct u.* from users u
  join group_members gm on gm.user_id = u.user_id
 where ...
```

or

```
select * from users u
 where u.user_id in (select user_id from group_members where ...)
   ...
```

Run "EXPLAIN SELECT" on both queries to see which one is faster in your case.